# Converting Uint16List to String or Integer in Dart/Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, modbus, uint16

I'm making an app, where I get data from Modbus protocol.
It returns basicly arrays with integers which I need to convert to Strings and Integers.

i.e. this should be a device name

```
[53440, 11714, 52701, 10449, 14157, 13876, 41, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 53440, 11714, 52701, 10449, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

I'm using dart:convert and following method

```
var deviceName = await client.readHoldingRegisters(0x90, 32)
var deviceStr = String.fromCharCodes(deviceName)
```

Result it followng:

```
타ⷂ췝⣑㝍㘴)
```

Maybe I'm doing something wrong or it's the real device name I need to translate

To get device os version I use following code

```
var version = await client.readHoldingRegisters(0x82, 2);
Result: [264, 0]
```

If I transfer it to the string i get this

```
Ĉ
```

What is the proper way to transfer Uint16List to strings/integer in Dart?

Comment: Modbus holding registers are 16-bit words (so 0000-FFFF) and `readHoldingRegisters` will return an array of these 16-bit values (one for each register you requested). What these values mean is controller dependent (and not covered in the [Modbus spec](https://www.modbus.org/docs/Modbus_Application_Protocol_V1_1b3.pdf)) so its not really possible to tell you how to decode this without information on the controller you are communicating with (most will have a sheet telling you what each register is and how the info is encoded).

Comment: Also your example code looks wrong (you put the data in `deviceName` but do not use that variable again - you don't say where `device` comes from).

Comment: @Brits it was a misstype in question, fixed it;
it says R16 in a sheet, so it's a 16 bit readonly

Comment: "it says R16 in a sheet" - that does not really help (The Modbus spec states that holding registers are  16 bits). Without details of the controller you are trying to communicate with its not possible to help further (I'd expect the documentation to say more than just "R16").

Comment: @Brits it says that 2 first registers contain 2 ASCII symbols, encoded with WIN-1251, is there more info I need in order to decode it? I also got working code in C# but it's using Encode C# library

Comment: [Win-1251](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251) is not the same thing as ASCII (ASCII is 7-bit and [53440, 11714] = [d0c0, 2dc2] so 3/4 bytes use the 8th bit). You could parse this as `PA-B` (noting that the letters are, I believe, Cyrillic). I would expect the documentation to provide further into; if you got it working in C# then post that code, the input/output, and your attempt at implementing the same thing in dart.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
final _uint16List = Uint16List.fromList(deviceName);
final _base64String = base64Encode(_uint16List);
```

Comment: Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument (Not a byte value at index 0: 0xd0c0): Uint16Array

That's the error